INotifyPropertyChanged does not work on UserControl
[note: this is from proprietary code, so I renamed variables, functions....I might have forgotten some, just let me know]
I use a combo box to select data from a list, that updates a SharedViewModel values
The Label component is updated but not my UserControlTest component
I expect the UserControlTest to display UPDATED values from the SharedViewModel
nothing budges, like if the UserControlTest was not updated

I forced the DataContext on the UserControlTest user control

I renamed UserControlTest local property to avoid name overlap

I used Binding Debugging, dont see anything wrong
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="DataTestChanged" >
  ...                                    
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeData, Source={StaticResource SharedViewModelInstance}, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource SomeDataToStringConverter }}" />
  ...
</ComboBox>

<Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeData, Source={StaticResource SharedViewModelInstance}, Mode=OneWay}"/>

<userControls:UserControlTest x:Name="dataSelector" 
                        SomeData2="{Binding Path=SomeData, Source={StaticResource SharedViewModelInstance}, Mode=OneWay}"
                        DataContext="{StaticResource SharedViewModelInstance}"
                        ></userControls:DataSelector >



The PropertyChanged gets triggered if I modify the data from another component in the same DataContext/Parent
private DataType _SomeData = new DataType();
public DataType SomeData
{
    get
    {
        return _SomeData;
    }
    set
    {
        _SomeData = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeData));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    //PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

I try to display the local data and the shared data in the UserComponent
none of them are changing when selecting something else from the combo
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <main:SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModelInstance"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource SomePanel}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="somePanel" Height="Auto" Orientation="Vertical"  >
        
        <!--displays global value from shared model view-->
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeData, Source={StaticResource SharedViewModelInstance}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <!--displays local data-->
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeData2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>            

        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

the code behind
public partial class UserControlTest: UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeData2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("SomeData2", typeof(DataType), typeof(UserControlTest));

    public DataType SomeData2
    {
        get
        {
            return (DataType)GetValue(SomeData2Property);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SomeData2Property, value);
        }
    }


It looks to me like in your user control you're creating a new resource with a key of SharedViewModelInstance. Presumably you're expecting it to use the same one as in your other control. Have you checked how many instances are being created?

(As an aside, I'd strongly encourage you to use less bold formatting in your post - I personally find it distracting to have that much formatting. Just bolding a single word here or there for emphasis is fine, but if about a third of your post is in bold, it's counterproductive IMO.)

If you want a globally shared instance that you define as a resource then define it in the App xaml resource dictionary and only there. You want a single shared instance.

but I use <main:SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModelInstance"/>in my user control...how do I use the same SharedViewModel then ?

ok, so by trying to debug the global model view in my component I accidentally recreated a new one...damn

@JonSkeet When I see how quickly some people tend to discard and vote down my questions, running away like kids ringing a door bell without any explanation, I tend to add bold to help the reader see what is the issue...sorry if I sometimes over do it

It seems you are missing an important point of how data binding in WPF is typically used. You would assign a view model instance to the DataContext property of the top-level view, e.g. the MainWindow. The value of the DataContext property is inherited by all child elements of the main view. Data bindings of properties of those child elements would not specify a Source or RelativeSource, but instead implicitly use the object in the DataContext as their source. See Data Binding Overview,

this is terrible design, what if your components need to be used in another project with a different implementation ?

@phil You have a wrong understanding of reusability and control design. Take the WPF ListBox control as an example. The way it is used. The way it can be used in any scenario - because it does not depend on any view model internally. Controls don't have their own view model classes. They are just data views and you feed data to them e.g. via a view model class. This way you achieve maximum reusability and customizability.

@phil Your control does not work without the SharedViewModel. That's bad. The view model is always linked to the model. And each application has its own model. How can you reuse that view model in different applications? A control always displays the data that is assigned to its properties e.g. via data binding.

There's a fundamental problem with your "project". You're kicking around an object ("DataType") that has no apparent string representation; and you're bindiing it to TextBlocks and Labels that expect "text" (i.e. "strings").

I found the solution to my problem.
This cannot be used in the USerControl as it is not using main instance but creating a new one
<UserControl.Resources>
    <main:SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModelInstance"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

This is quiet confusing since the one declared in main looks like this
<local:SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModelInstance"/>


Is this an answer?

that solved my problem indeed

Maybe you can elaborate it a bit more for others and then mark it as the answer.

Hope my edit is ok - I edited to clarify this is the solution to your problem. As Daaran mentioned, it could also be helpful to mark this as the accepted answer so that future readers can more easily tell that that's what worked for you.

If you want to share an instance amongst several classes then you must make sure that all these classes reference exact same instance.
Whenever you write...
<SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModelInstance" />

...you are creating a new instance of the SharedViewModel object. Modifying one does not modify the other. Like when smashing in the window of one house does not break the window of another house.
You can control the scope of the shared instance by choosing the apropriate resource dictionary.
If you want to share the SharedViewModel application wide then define it in the App.xaml resource dictionary.
App.xaml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <SharedViewModel x:Key="SharedViewModelInstance" />
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Now you can reference it from anywhere in your application using {StaticResource}.
However, it should be said that the best way to share data in views is to make proper use of DataContext and data binding. For example, when setting the MainWindow.DataContext property to SharedViewModel all child elements including your UserCocntrol will inherit this DataContext.
This useful feature known as DataContext inheritance (in context of dependency property inheritance), enables to manage data contexts gracefully using good old composition. A root view model e.g., MainViewModel, hosts one or more child view models where the MainViewModel is "global" as it is assigned to the visual root's DataContext e.g., Window.DataContext. The child view model classes can then be referenced to create more specialized data context scopes (see example) whenever needed.
Additionally, you should never reference any DataContext (and therefore view model classes from inside custom controls. Instead implement a dependency property for the data that you need from the DataContext (or view model class) and provide this value by assigning an external binding, the way you would provide a source collection to the ListBox by binding a collection to the ListBox.ItemsSource property - ListBox does not reference the DataContext or your view model classes directly.
Example
The following example shows how to design a custom control properly so that it does not know any view model classes.
It also shows how to create different data context scopes using composition. This pattern also allows for easy data sharing.
UserControlTest.xaml.cs
This UserControl does not depend on any view model. The internal controls get their data from the dependency properties of the UserControl.
The client of this UserControl knows the DataContext and is responsible to provide the data by assigning them to the dependency properties.
public partial class UserControlTest : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataFromSharedViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DataFromSharedViewModel", 
    typeof(DataType), 
    typeof(UserControlTest));

  public DataType DataFromSharedViewModel
  {
    get => (DataType)GetValue(DataFromSharedViewModelProperty);
    set => SetValue(DataFromSharedViewModelProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeData2Property = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SomeData2", 
    typeof(DataType), 
    typeof(UserControlTest));

  public DataType SomeData2
  {
    get => (DataType)GetValue(SomeData2Property);
    set => SetValue(SomeData2Property, value);
  }
}

UserControlTest.xaml
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
  <StackPanel>
        
  <!-- 
    Displays global value from SharedViewModel 
    (implicitly as the value is provided by the client of this UserControl) 
  -->
  <Label Content="{Binding Path=DataFromSharedViewModel, ElementName=Root}"/>
   
  <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeData2, ElementName=Root}"/>            

  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>

MainViewModel.cs
The master or view model that uses composition to expose child view models that can provide a more specialized DataContext for the view.
MainViewModel is the root of the composition tree.
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private object someDataFromMainViewModel;
  public object SomeDataFromMainViewModel
  {
    get => this.someDataFromMainViewModel;
    set
    {
      this.someDataFromMainViewModel = value;
      OnPropertyChanged()
    }
  }

  // Use composition
  public MoreSpecializedViewModel MoreSpecializedViewModel { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
    => this.MoreSpecializedViewModel = new MoreSpecializedViewModel();
}

MoreSpecializedViewModel.cs
public class MoreSpecializedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private object someDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel;
  public object SomeDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel
  {
    get => this.someDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel;
    set => 
    {
      this.someDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel = value;
      OnPropertyChanged()
    }
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml.cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();

    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

MainWindow.xaml
In this example MainViewModel is "global" because it is the DataContext of all elements that are a child of MainWindow. If an element requires a more specialized DataContext it can get this from the MainViewModel.
<!-- 
  All children of Window share the same view model instance
  (in this case it's an instance of MainViewModel). 
-->
<Window>
  <StackPanel>

    <!-- Bind to common/shared MainViewModel -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeDataFromMainViewModel}" />

    <!-- 
      Bind to common/shared MainViewModel 
      and to a more specialized view model for this context.

      This usage example also shows how to feed external data 
      to the UserControl without the UserControl having to know 
      any view model classes.
    -->
    <UserControl SomeData2={Binding MoreSpecializedViewModel.SomeDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel}"
                 DataFromSharedViewModel="{Binding SomeDataFromMainViewModel}" />

    <!-- 
      Create a more specialized data context scope 
      nested in to the parent MainViewModel data context scope.
      Now, all children of StackPanel share the same view model instance,
      which is different from the parent DataContext scope
      (in this case it's an instance of MoreSpecializedViewModel). 
    -->
    <StackPanel DataContext={Binding MoreSpecializedViewModel}">
      <TextBox Text="{Bindig SomeDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel}" />
      <Button Content="{Bindig SomeDataFromMoreSpecializedViewModel}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>


only one instance please, but I dont share it among components, they are linked through binding, more portable, each components does not have to know about the outside world

but thanks for the time spent and the example

"only one instance please, but I dont share it among components, they are linked through binding," - What does that mean? "each components does not have to know about the outside world" - And what does that mean? Your UserControl knows a lot about "the outside world" as it is tightly copuled to it't DataContext. That's not "portable" at all. I really don't understand what you mean. It looks like you have a wrong  understanding.  But I don't know because I don't understand what you are sayinfg. Can you explain that to me, please?

I don't understand the problem very well.
But if you use your UserControlTest inside MainWindow, the UserControlTest is associated with the same ViewModel of MainWindow. So all the properties must be in the ViewModel (let's call it MainWindowViewModel).
On the other hand, if you want data to appear in your custom control every time you select an item from the ComboBox, you need a property in the ViewModel that is associated with the SelectedItem of the ComboBox.
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    namespace Example
    {
        public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private ObservableCollection<string> _comboBoxItems;
            public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxItems
            {
                get { return _comboBoxItems; }
                set
                {
                    _comboBoxItems = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
    
            private string _yourItem;
            public string YourItem
            {
                get { return _yourItem; }
                set
                {
                    _yourItem= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
    
            public MainWindowViewModel()
            {
                // Inicializar la colección de elementos del ComboBox
                ComboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<string>
                {
                    "Item 1",
                    "Item 2",
                    "Item 3"
                };
    
                // Asignar un elemento predeterminado seleccionado (si lo deseas)
                SelectedItem = ComboBoxItems[0];
            }
    
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

MainWindow.xaml:
<Window x:Class="SampleApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height = "Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height = "*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- Otros controles aquí -->
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding YourItem}" />
        <UserControlTest Grid.Row="1"
                         x:Name="dataSelector" 
                         SomeData2="{Binding Path=YourItem, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSource=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

Try to see if it works for you and tell us.
